# Non convergence of approximations of the identity via convolutions in the operator norm of $\mathcal L( C^0_0(\mathbb R^d)))$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $ C^0_0(\mathbb R^d) $ :=  ({  f :  $\mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R $ s.t. $ \lim_{||x||\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ }, $||\cdot||_\infty$).\
Let $\rho \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R)$ and let for $\epsilon >0$, $\rho_{\epsilon}(x)$ := $\epsilon^{-d}\rho(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$.
Prove that the operators $$T_{\epsilon} :  C^0_0(\mathbb R^d) \rightarrow C^0_0(\mathbb R^d) | f\mapsto \rho_{\epsilon}\ast f$$ do not converge to the identity in the operator norm for $\epsilon$ going to $0$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try with $d=1,f(x)=(1-|x|)1_{|x|<1}, f_n(x)=f(nx)$. Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|f_n\|_{L^1}=0$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|\rho_\epsilon \ast f_n\|_\infty=0$.